# python how to download or upload file on remote machine from reverse shell

Tags: python, sockets

how can i upload or download file from remote machine using reverse shell, is it with IO: for example

def download(sock, command):

```
file = open(command)

fd =  file.read()

sock.send(fd)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I had to look up what a reverse shell was, and this looks like you're trying to hack someone else's machine. It's unlikely you'll get much help here for that specifically. Please take the [tour], read about [ask], and see what's on topic in the [help/on-topic]

Comment: Also see [Should questions about programming viruses and malware be allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262656/should-questions-about-programming-viruses-and-malware-be-allowed). I think the main reason for closing this question though is it is poorly asked.